# Как записать значения введённые с клавиатуры в указатель списка Pithon?

Tags: python, list, список, ввод, обработка-ошибок

Хочу в переменную-список char3 ввести новый вложенный список. Но значения введённые с клавиатуры не воспринимаются, выдаётся ошибка
"list indices must be integers, not str" . Подскажите исправить ошибку и записать значения в список char3.

```
elif vvod == '3':  
    vvod4 = input('Введите значение предпосылки Высокая-1, Средняя-2, Низкая-3')
    vvod5 = input('Введите заключение да-1, нет-2')
    d = char3[vvod4]
    char3.append(d)
```

Comment: Все воспринимается.

Comment: input всегда возвращает строки. Индексами списков могут быть только числа. нужно привести введенную строку в число с помощью функции int

Answer (score 1):

В этой части кода:

```
d = char3[vvod4]
```

Вы присваиваете переменной d значение элемента char3 с порядковым номером vvod4, но тип vvod4 - str, поэтому появляется ошибка.
Чтобы выбрать элемент, попробуйте изменить тип vvod4:

```
d = char3[int(vvod4)]
```

Если же вы хотите в список char3 добавить список [vvod4], то попробуйте следующий код:

```
elif vvod == '3':  
    vvod4 = input('Введите значение предпосылки Высокая-1, Средняя-2, Низкая-3')
    vvod5 = input('Введите заключение да-1, нет-2')
    d = [vvod4]
    char3.append(d)
```

Или просто:

```
elif vvod == '3':  
    vvod4 = input('Введите значение предпосылки Высокая-1, Средняя-2, Низкая-3')
    vvod5 = input('Введите заключение да-1, нет-2')
    char3.append([vvod4])
```

Answer (score -1):

Большое Спасибо за помощь.
В итоге все получилось спасибо
Сделал так:

...
elif vvod == '3':
vvod4 = input('Введите значение предпосылки Высокая-1, Средняя-2, Низкая-3  Вы ввыели:')
vvod5 = input('Введите заключение да-1, нет-2  Вы ввыели:')

```
        d = char0[0],char1[0],char0[1],char1[int(vvod4)],char0[2],char2[0],char0[1],char2[int(vvod5)]
        char3.append(d)
```